# How to include parentheses in R markdown when writing ggplot axis titles?

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is just a simple syntax question but I can't figure it out. I have a very simple plot to make, and in my CSV file I have a column with this title: Revenue (millions). When I write the code block:

`{r}
ggplot(tweets, aes(x=TweetRate, y=Revenue (millions) )) +geom_point()`

It displays and error and says could not find function "Revenue". Why isn't it reading the part within parentheses? I tried all sorts of ways around, like Revenue_(millions), Revenue (millions), but it always stops at the first parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `y = \`Revenue (millions)\``

Comment: `Revenue (millions)` works! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
test <- read_csv("Desktop/test.csv")

ggplot(test, aes(x=TweetRate, y="Revenue (millions)" )) + geom_point()